# add to collection_select dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, collection-select

I have 3 Models: Course, Unit and Plan.
relations are like:

```
Course has_many units
Unit belongs_to course

Plan has_and_belongs_to_many units
Unit has_and_belongs_to_many plans
```

In the create_plan page, I have a collection_select to get units of my plan;
but units don't have title,they use their course title.
I want to show the course title in the collection_select.
how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate title to the course

```
class Unit
  belongs_to course
  delegate :title, to: :course
end

<%= f.collection_select(:unit_id, Unit.all, :id, :title, prompt: true) %>
```